# Changing v-card background color based on card value

Tags: vue.js

I am currently working with a v-row of v-cards and am struggling to change the background color of a certain card based on the card's value. I have it set up here so that if the value of the card is equal to the current value (input by the user), then that card's background should be white, `#FFFFFF`, otherwise the card background should be black, `#000000`. This is what I have setup, and for some reason it is not working. Does anyone know what I have wrong?

```
<v-row>
    <v-card
      v-for="values in cards"
      :key="value"
      color="currVal == value ? '#FFFFFF' : '#000000'"
      :class="'ma-2 pa-3'"
      outlined
      tile
    >{{ value }}</v-card>
</v-row>
```

Comment: Do you get any error? First it is better to use ===. Check ur ternary if syntax please. Could you post ur cards key values?

Comment: @KickButtowski Thanks for the response. I do not get any error. I changed the == to === instead. The ternary syntax is correct. I verified this by replacing `{ value }` with `{ currVal }` to see if the text would update properly, and it is working when I do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your color is a javascript expression, you need to `v-bind` `color` parameter:

```
<v-row>
    <v-card
      v-for="value in cards"
      :key="value"
      :color="currVal === value ? '#FFFFFF' : '#000000'"
      class="ma-2 pa-3"
      outlined
      tile
    >{{ value }}</v-card>
</v-row>
```

Minor: since `class` is just a string, no need `v-bind`.

Comment: Just a tip, `:` means dynamic attributes :D